# ios activity indicator and background interaction

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using an activity indicator.It is working fine. I can still interact(click) with my button. I don't want that. I don't want to interact with background.
Could any can tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the clicks or other user interactions by setting,

> self.button.userInteractionEnabled = false
>
> or
>
> self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

Even better use libraries like https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD that does the job for you.